# Xcode 9.1/9.2 beta immediately crashes on launch

Tags: ios, xcode9

A few days ago, when I would open my Xcode project and navigate to the storyboard, Xcode would hang and then ultimately not respond and then I would have to force quit. I looked up the issue and saw a suggestion to delete ~/Library/Developer folder...**now the Xcode window doesn't even appear**. **The application just immediately crashes without opening.**

Steps I've taken, in chronological order:

- Deleted and reinstalled Xcode > did not solve
- Upgraded from macOS Sierra to High Sierra > did not solve
- Tried both Xcode 9.1 and 9.2 beta > did not solve
- Reinstalled Command Line Tools > did not solve

Still nothing. I do have a 2011 MacBook Pro, and I'm wondering if it may just be an issue with my machine, or if it is indeed a result of losing ~/Library/Developer.

Any suggestions on how to recover necessary files or successfully open Xcode are appreciated.

Comment: Re-install official XCode from the app store. It will recreate the folder with the necessary files

Comment: I've tried that several times. Xcode from app store as well as Xcode from my developer account. Still no luck :(

Comment: Can you open other projects, i.e. make a new project and open it?

Comment: I was missing PrivateFrameworks in the developer file. Getting that from someone else's machine that runs Xcode solved the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem. In fact like you I also manually deleted the Developer folder (then I took a step further and like an idiot I also emptied the trash).

There is an easier way of fixing this problem than asking someone for their copy of PrivateFrameworks folder. You can just run XcodeSystemResources.pkg in order to setup PrivateFrameworks for you.

[image: XcodeSystemResources.pkg]

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88570

> I didn't reinstall the Xcode 9 but just ran the package
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/Packages/XcodeSystemResources.pkg.
>   And the Xcode 9 started to work.

> XcodeSystemResources.pkg is supposed to be installed on the initial
>   launch of Xcode.app.  Can you explain why that wasn't the case?  Did
>   you manually delete
>   /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework?  If you
>   delete that after the first launch, Xcode doesn't know to reinstall
>   those packages for you.

Comment: Thanks! I resolved this a while back just by copying a friend's developer folder.

Comment: Yep I saw your comment regarding that, but I had no one to copy that missing folder from, so I had to look for another way. I saw that your question was still open and there was no accepted answer yet, so decided to post my solution in case someone comes across your question with same problem.