# Can't open up Xcode, without it shouting down

Tags: xcode

I start to get problems with the Xcode beta 2 version, the simulator wont launch when using playground. So a delete it and downloaded Xcode from app store. And now when a just open up the regular Xcode this comes up.

[image]

Comment: I use my laptop in Swedish, but it says in the picture that Xcode unexpectedly ended.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 9.1/9.2 beta immediately crashes on launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47086160/xcode-9-1-9-2-beta-immediately-crashes-on-launch). Check it's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47609738/2857130)